# Single column with value counts from multiple column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, multiple-columns

I would like to sum the frequencies over multiple columns with pandas. The amount of columns can vary between 2-15 columns. Here is an example of just 3 columns:

```
code1    code2    code3
27       5        56
534      27       78
27       312      55
89       312      27
```

And I would like to have the following result:

```
code    frequency
5       1
27      4
55      1
56      2
78      1
312     2
534     1
```

To count values inside one column is not the problem, just need a sum of all frequencies in a dataframe a value can appear, no matter the amount of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and take the [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on the resulting series:

```
df.stack().value_counts().sort_index()

5      1
27     4
55     1
56     1
78     1
89     1
312    2
534    1
dtype: int64
```